# Sar vs df -h... discrepancy between percentage of root filesystem

Tags: linux, filesystems, disk-usage, sar

why does sar give me 8.14% of root filesystem used and df -h gives me 9% for the same root filesystem? I was thinking df may be rounding the value, but if so it would be 8%.

```
localhost one # sar -F 1 1                      
Linux 4.4.26-gentoo (localhost)     05/15/17    _x86_64_    (8 CPU)

18:39:08     MBfsfree  MBfsused   %fsused  %ufsused     Ifree     Iused    %Iused FILESYSTEM
18:39:09       118401     10485      8.14     13.23   7853529    535079      6.38 /dev/mapper/root
18:39:09          463        25      5.14     12.48     32403       365      1.11 /dev/sda1

Summary:     MBfsfree  MBfsused   %fsused  %ufsused     Ifree     Iused    %Iused FILESYSTEM
Summary:       118401     10485      8.14     13.23   7853529    535079      6.38 /dev/mapper/root
Summary:          463        25      5.14     12.48     32403       365      1.11 /dev/sda1
```

---

```
localhost one # df -h
Filesystem        Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev               10M  4.0K   10M   1% /dev
/dev/mapper/root  126G   11G  110G   9% /
tmpfs             794M  492K  793M   1% /run
shm               3.9G   19M  3.9G   1% /dev/shm
cgroup_root        10M     0   10M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1         488M   26M  428M   6% /boot
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you divide the used space by the total space, you get 10485/(118401+10485) ≈ 0.08135, which sar rounds to 8.14%.

By default, on an ext2/ext3/ext4 filesystem, 5% of the space is reserved to root. The “Avail” value displayed by the `df` command does not include this reserved space in the total space (i.e. it performs the calculation based on 95% of the total space, which is all that a non-root user can use), so the calculation it makes is 
10485 / ((118401+10485)*0.95) ≈ 0.08563, which is rounded to 9%.

The reserved space allows the system to keep running for a bit after it's almost full. For example, logs can still be written for a while, which can be a big help in diagnosing what filled the disk. For a partition that doesn't contain `/var`, the reserved space is less useful, but a filesystem that's 95% full is likely to get fragmented anyway, so it's a bad idea for performance to go much beyond that.